# Clustering of Items in a UI-Matrix with package skmeans

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix, items

i've got a specific question on the package "skmeans". 
I considered the movielens100k dataset which involves "u.data" which is a dataset of four columns in the following order "User","Item","Rating" and "Timestamp". I've implemented the following code:

```
UI_ratings_raw <- scan(file="u1.base",what=list(user=0,movie=0,rating=0),flush=TRUE)
UI_ratings_sparse <- sparseMatrix(UI_ratings_raw$user,UI_ratings_raw$movie,x=UI_ratings_raw$rating,dims =c(943,1682)) #Eintrag aus Forum github siehe R Datei Matrixreduzierung
UI_ratings_sparse_dgT <- as(UI_ratings_sparse,"dgTMatrix")

install.packages("skmeans")
library(skmeans)

install.packages("cluster")
library(cluster)

UI_ratings_sparse_clust_sk <- skmeans(UI_ratings_sparse_dgT,20,control = list(verbose=TRUE)) 
summary(silhouette(UI_ratings_sparse_clust_sk))
```

Clustering performed very well but only on the users side. Is there any possibility to change the code in that way that i'm able to compute Cluster for the Items?

Comment: Transpose the data, run again? K-means is not symmetric? Consider doing real matrix factorization.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible because it's a very sparse matrix. So what do you want to transpose? If i want to transpose the matrices the function skmeans gives me a error "zero rows are not allowed". thank you very much for your help

Comment: Matrix factorization is *good* for sparse data? There are many methods designed for such data. That error you got there is probably because you had a zero column in your origonal data? Remove it.

Comment: Yes it is if you minimize the errors with stochastic gradient descent in terms of recommendations ;)  so what methods do you suggest? are there any packages in r?

Comment: Sorry, stupid touchscreen keyboard keeps changing dots into questionmarks. Either way, you have at least one zero-column. No algorithm will yield anything useful on that item (no data!). I don't use R, it is too slow.